# How to generate data class from class instance

Tags: kotlin, code-generation, data-class

I've got some configuration values in a JSON file which I want to parse via gson to a data-class. I want to generate a new class, based on the created data-class where the values are final.
This all should happen during my CI-Pipeline and the generated class should then be used when my application is running.

Simple example to clarify:

I've got this data class

```
data class MyDataClass(val name:String, val age:Int)
```

and via parsing (gson) a instance like this is created

```
MyDataClass("john", 42)
```

Is there a way to create a (data) class based on the new instance of MyDataClass so anything like this will be created?

```
class MyDataClassFinal{
  val name = "john"
  val age = 42
}
```

Comment: Your initial data class is already "final", and its properties as well. This is the default in Kotlin. What are you looking for exactly that is not already there?

Answer (score 0):

> I've got some configuration values in a json file wich I want to parse via gson to a data-class. I want to generate a new class, based on the created data-class where the values are final.

There is nothing for you to do here. The data class, as you've described it, is final. It is not `open` so the class is final and the fields are `val`s and only set via constructor, so they can't be changed, so they too are final.

You can see the Java equivalent of the class by going to doing a search for "Actions", looking for `Kotlin Bytecode`, then hit `Decompile` to see the Java source. It looks like this:

```
@Metadata(
   mv = {1, 1, 18},
   bv = {1, 0, 3},
   k = 1,
   d1 = {"\u0000 \n\u0002\u0018\u0002\n\u0002\u0010\u0000\n\u0000\n\u0002\u0010\u000e\n\u0000\n\u0002\u0010\b\n\u0002\b\t\n\u0002\u0010\u000b\n\u0002\b\u0004\b\u0086\b\u0018\u00002\u00020\u0001B\u0015\u0012\u0006\u0010\u0002\u001a\u00020\u0003\u0012\u0006\u0010\u0004\u001a\u00020\u0005¢\u0006\u0002\u0010\u0006J\t\u0010\u000b\u001a\u00020\u0003HÆ\u0003J\t\u0010\f\u001a\u00020\u0005HÆ\u0003J\u001d\u0010\r\u001a\u00020\u00002\b\b\u0002\u0010\u0002\u001a\u00020\u00032\b\b\u0002\u0010\u0004\u001a\u00020\u0005HÆ\u0001J\u0013\u0010\u000e\u001a\u00020\u000f2\b\u0010\u0010\u001a\u0004\u0018\u00010\u0001HÖ\u0003J\t\u0010\u0011\u001a\u00020\u0005HÖ\u0001J\t\u0010\u0012\u001a\u00020\u0003HÖ\u0001R\u0011\u0010\u0004\u001a\u00020\u0005¢\u0006\b\n\u0000\u001a\u0004\b\u0007\u0010\bR\u0011\u0010\u0002\u001a\u00020\u0003¢\u0006\b\n\u0000\u001a\u0004\b\t\u0010\n¨\u0006\u0013"},
   d2 = {"Lcore/lib/extensions/MyDataClass;", "", "name", "", "age", "", "(Ljava/lang/String;I)V", "getAge", "()I", "getName", "()Ljava/lang/String;", "component1", "component2", "copy", "equals", "", "other", "hashCode", "toString", "treking-android.dominicore-android"}
)
public final class MyDataClass {
   @NotNull
   private final String name;
   private final int age;

   @NotNull
   public final String getName() {
      return this.name;
   }

   public final int getAge() {
      return this.age;
   }

   public MyDataClass(@NotNull String name, int age) {
      Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull(name, "name");
      super();
      this.name = name;
      this.age = age;
   }

   @NotNull
   public final String component1() {
      return this.name;
   }

   public final int component2() {
      return this.age;
   }

   @NotNull
   public final MyDataClass copy(@NotNull String name, int age) {
      Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull(name, "name");
      return new MyDataClass(name, age);
   }

   // $FF: synthetic method
   public static MyDataClass copy$default(MyDataClass var0, String var1, int var2, int var3, Object var4) {
      if ((var3 & 1) != 0) {
         var1 = var0.name;
      }

      if ((var3 & 2) != 0) {
         var2 = var0.age;
      }

      return var0.copy(var1, var2);
   }

   @NotNull
   public String toString() {
      return "MyDataClass(name=" + this.name + ", age=" + this.age + ")";
   }

   public int hashCode() {
      String var10000 = this.name;
      return (var10000 != null ? var10000.hashCode() : 0) * 31 + this.age;
   }

   public boolean equals(@Nullable Object var1) {
      if (this != var1) {
         if (var1 instanceof MyDataClass) {
            MyDataClass var2 = (MyDataClass)var1;
            if (Intrinsics.areEqual(this.name, var2.name) && this.age == var2.age) {
               return true;
            }
         }

         return false;
      } else {
         return true;
      }
   }
}
```

As you can see, the class, it's fields, and their accessors are all `final`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. No, I don't look for the default parameter. I want to create a complete new class (also a new class file) based on the values from the instance.

Comment: Of what use is creating a new class file from an existing class file that has the same data ... ?

Comment: I updated my question.

The generation and the usage are at different stages of the application. The generation is running via CI-Builds and the usage is while running the application.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.copy()` and modify only the parameters you need to. For example:

```
val joe = MyDataClass(“Joe”, 42)
val mary = joe.copy(name = “Mary”) // age is 42
```

Comment: I updated my question, maybe no it's more clear what i try to say :)

Comment: You want to define a new, distinct class from MyDataClass? Not sure because you gave it the same name and it has the same properties, so I don’t know why it should need to be a distinct class.